# My SQL returning duplicated entries for UNION for two table join in each SQL

Tags: mysql

for query

```
( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description, ct.name 
from client c , client_type ct where fname = 'Ade Kannu ' and ct._id = c.type_id) 
UNION
( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description, ct.name 
from client c , client_type ct  where c.lname = 'Ade Kannu ' and ct._id = c.type_id)
UNION
 ( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description, ct.name from client c , client_type ct   where c.fname like '%Ade Kannu %' and ct._id = c.type_id)
 UNION 
 ( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description, ct.name from client c , client_type ct   where c.lname like '%Ade Kannu %' and ct._id = c.type_id)  
 UNION 
 ( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description, ct.name from client c , client_type ct   where c.title_content like '%Ade Kannu %' or c.key_value like '%Ade Kannu %' ) UNION 
 ( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description, ct.name from client c , client_type ct   where c.fname like '%Ade%' or c.lname like '%Ade%'  or c.title_content like '%Ade%' or c.key_value like '%Ade%' and ct._id = c.type_id)  
 UNION 
 ( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description, ct.name from client c , client_type ct   where c.fname like '%Kannu%' or c.lname like '%Kannu%'  or c.title_content like '%Kannu%' or c.key_value like '%Kannu%' and ct._id = c.type_id)  
 UNION 
 ( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description, ct.name from client c , client_type ct   where c.fname like '%' or c.lname like '%'  or c.title_content like '%' or c.key_value like '%' and ct._id = c.type_id)  limit 0 , 10 ;
```

My sql returning duplicates.

in the same case

```
( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description 
from client c where fname = 'Ade Kannu ') 
UNION
( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description 
from client c  where c.lname = 'Ade Kannu ')
UNION
 ( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description from client c   where c.fname like '%Ade Kannu %')
 UNION 
 ( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description from client c   where c.lname like '%Ade Kannu %')  
 UNION 
 ( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description from client c   where c.title_content like '%Ade Kannu %' or c.key_value like '%Ade Kannu %' )
 UNION 
 ( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description from client c   where c.fname like '%Ade%' or c.lname like '%Ade%'  or c.title_content like '%Ade%' or c.key_value like '%Ade%')  
 UNION 
 ( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description from client c   where c.fname like '%Kannu%' or c.lname like '%Kannu%'  or c.title_content like '%Kannu%' or c.key_value like '%Kannu%')  
 UNION 
 ( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description from client c   where c.fname like '%' or c.lname like '%'  or c.title_content like '%' or c.key_value like '%') limit 0, 10
```

its not returning duplicates.

Basically I want `client_type` `name` which is in another table and its foreign key in present in `client` table. could some one help me please

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct function. like this

```
select distinct client_id, fname, lname, type_id, short_description  from (
( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description 
from client c where fname = 'Ade Kannu ') 
UNION
( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description 
from client c  where c.lname = 'Ade Kannu ')
UNION
 ( select c.client_id, c.fname, c.lname, c.type_id, c.short_description from client c   where c.fname like '%Ade Kannu %')
 ....
....
....
...) a
```